# Fetch first few rows of a table from a HTML page in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I am making a GET request to this website through python.

```
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/forecast/archive/?C=M;O=D
```

However, it downloads a HTML page with a huge table through the following python code

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/forecast/archive/?C=M;O=D'
r = requests.get(input_url_path)
url_list = r.text
```

This takes a lot of time and space.

Is there a way to download the first N rows of the table on this page?

Answer (score 0):

Use streaming, and set your chunksize to get however much data you want back.  You can iterate over the chunks until you get as many links as you want.  It will probably go over by a few depending on the chunk size but it'll get you pretty close.

```
import requests
import re

n_rows = 100
url = 'https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/forecast/archive/?C=M;O=D'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

links = []
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=500000):
        links.extend(re.findall(r'href="([^?\/].*?)"',str(x)))
        if len(links) >= n_rows:
                     break
```

Comment: I also need to get the date/time from each row from this page